# Initializing a Vector of Objects from a .txt file

Tags: c++, object, data-structures, file-io

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include "stock.h"
int main(){
    double balance =0, tempPrice=0;
    string tempStr;

    vector < Stock > portfolio;
    typedef vector<Stock>::iterator StockIt;

    ifstream fileIn( "Results.txt" );
    for(StockIt i = portfolio.begin(); i != portfolio.end(); i++)
    {

        while ( !fileIn.eof( ))
        {
            getline(fileIn,tempStr);
            i->setSymbol(tempStr);

            fileIn >> tempPrice;
            i->setPrice(tempPrice);

            getline(fileIn,tempStr);
            i->setDate(tempStr);
        }
        fileIn.close();
    }
    for(StockIt i = portfolio.begin(); i != portfolio.end(); i++){
        cout<<i->getSymbol() <<endl;
        cout<<i->getPrice() <<endl;
        cout<<i->getDate() <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
```

}

Sample text file, Results.txt:

```
GOOG    569.964 11/17/2010
MSFT    29.62   11/17/2010
YHOO    15.38   11/17/2010
AAPL    199.92  11/17/2010
```

Now obviously, I want this program to create a vector of Stock Objects which has the appropriate set/get functionality for object: `Stock(string, double, string)`.

Once that is done, I want to print out each individual member of each Object in the vector.

One thing that boggles my mind about `fstream`, is how can it decipher spaces and end of lines, and intelligently read strings/ints/doubles and place them into the appropriate data type? Maybe it can't...and I have to add an entirely new functionality?

now it would seem that I'm not actually creating a new object for each iteration of the loop? I *think* would need to do something along the lines of:

`portfolio.push_back(new Stock(string, double, string));`? I'm just not entirely sure how to get to that point.

Also, this code should be interchangeable with `std::list` as well as `std::vector`. This program compiles without error, however, there is zero output.

Comment: It knows how to read strings/int/doubles correctly because `>>` is overloaded for each one of those cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, iterating over the vector only makes sense when it isn't empty. So remove the line:

```
for(StockIt i = portfolio.begin(); i != portfolio.end(); i++)
```

because otherwise the contents of this loop will never be executed.

Second, you have problems with your input reading: you use `getline` for the first field, which would read the values of all 3 fields on the line into the tempStr variable.

Third, you shouldn't use `while(!fileIn.eof())` - the `eof` function only returns true *after* you tried to read past the end of the file. Instead, use:

```
while (fileIn >> symbol >> price >> date) {
    //here you should create a Stock object and call push_back on the vector.
}
```

This will read the three fields, which are separated by spaces.

Comment: what's the appropriate way to separate an entire line into 3 separate fields? So I get rid of tempStr and turn it into 2x separate string variables, `string tempSymbol` and `string tempDate`.

Comment: The appropriate way is the one I showed in my answer. `symbol`, `price`, and `date` are string variables.

Comment: also, @interjay, assuming I have an overloaded constructor for my `Stock` object, within the While loop I would create the following code `portfolio.push_back(new Stock(tempSymbol, tempPrice, tempDate));` I'm asking this, because i'm just baffled that spaces in Results.txt are automatically recognized? I'm not use to things being that simple...

Comment: It's better to use `std::getline` to read a whole line at a time, then parse it (possibly using `std::istringstream`) into the components.  If you say `while (fileIn >> symbol >> price >> date)` your program will happily accept invalid input, such as a file where all the newlines have been replaced by tabs.

Comment: @Staypuft: don't use `new`, just use `portfolio.push_back(Stock(..params..));`. The `>>` operator (with a string on the right-hand side) reads the input until the next whitespace (and discards whitespace if needed), so it should work appropriately here.

Comment: @John Zwinck: Wouldn't it be better if it also handled input separated by tabs instead of newlines? Anyway, I tried to keep things simple because this seemed like too much of a beginner question to go into error handling in detail.

Comment: Silently accepting malformed input is a big source of bugs.  Better to decide what the input format is (in this case, tabular with newlines), and accept only input that conforms.  I'm not even talking about full error handling here...we do newbies no great service if we teach them simpler methods that are actually harmful.

Comment: currently with this code `while (fileIn >> tempSymbol>> tempPrice >> tempDate){          portfolio.push_back(Stock(tempSymbol>>tempPrice>>tempDate));}` I'm getting the following compile time error `no match for 'operator>>' in tempSymbol >> tempPrice`

Comment: @Staypuft: `>>` is used to read input. To pass parameters to a function (such as the `Stock` constructor), separate them with commas.

Comment: wow, @interjay, don't know how I missed that. Been coding for like 12 hours (this is just a sand-boxed test program of a concept I was having trouble with)

Answer (score 1):

Few issues in your code.
the first for loop runs on an empty portfolio vector, as the vector is not initialized (no objects are being pushed to it) the begin() and end() are the same.
you should read line by line from the fstream until EOF, then push objects to the vector.
each line you read, you should split (tokenize) into the 3 parts, and create a new Stock object to be pushed to the vector.

Another side feedback, whenever using an stl iterator, use ++itr on for loops, it will run much more fast